# Inserting rows into Google Fusion Table from Winform/console app

Tags: .net, winforms, google-fusion-tables

I need to be able to insert rows into a fusion table without user input. This will be an executable that will run nightly to make sure the fusion table is relatively up to date.
I don't need user information... all I want to do is insert some rows so I can use the fusion table to create a map.

I've been trying different approaches all day following Google's worthless api samples. I either end up with exceptions bubbling up from their DOTNet library or I just get authorization required errors.

Is it even possible to do what I want without user intervention? It seems every example still wants the user to "accept" something and then provide token to the application.

Any example, comment, guidance is appreciated.

Below are some of the code I've tried.. it seems like if I can just get the stupid token to pass into an httpwebrequest header I could put an insert into the body of the request and do what I want.. but I can't even get anything to connect.

This just bombs miserably in the assertion class with an httpwebrequest error

```
            AssertionFlowClient provider = new AssertionFlowClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, cert);
        provider.ServiceAccountId = devEmail;
        provider.Scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables";

        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(provider, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);

        return new FusiontablesService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    Authenticator = auth,
                    ApplicationName = "apptest"
                });
```

This also fails...

```
 NativeApplicationClient x = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, clientID, clientSecret);   
        string token;
        try
        {
            IAuthorizationState s = x.GetClientAccessToken(new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables" });
            token = s.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            string ex = exception.Message;
        }
```